# Can you only use a Twilio number to receive calls and perform an action on an incoming call?

Tags: ios, twilio

From my reading I garnered that you have to purchase a Twilio number then you can perform
a programmatic action on an incoming call or phone number to that purchased Twilio number?

I need to be able to have any existing number not a Twilio number receive a call
then perform an action on that call or phone number based on information in my database regarding that phone number, be it reject or allow the call. Is this something Twilio can do?

Comment: You have no access to the phone except to place calls through to the phone app via it's tel:// url scheme.

Comment: Why was this tagged with "mysql"?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't intercept any call. In other words, you don't have any API that allows you to perform anything starting from a phone call.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options;
- Port your existing numbers (http://www.twilio.com/help/faq/porting)
- Point your existing numbers to Twilio DDI's